# Apparent contradiction involving a.e. differentiability of strictly increasing functions

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse, cantor-set

$U:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a continuous function, $U(1)>U(0)$ and $U'$ exists almost everywhere. Let $\max U([0,1])=\overline{v}$. Pick $\underline{v} \in (U(0), \overline{v})$. Define $\psi: [\underline{v},\overline{v}] \rightarrow [0,1]$ as $\psi(v)=\min\limits_{\theta \in [0,1]}\{U(\theta)=v\}$.

Claim: $\psi$ is strictly  increasing.

Proof: By continuity of $U$, either $U(\theta)<v$ or $U(\theta)>v$ for all $\theta<\psi(v)$. $U(0)<\underline{v} \leq v$. Therefore the former is the only possibility. For any $\theta<\psi(v) \implies U(\theta)<v'\;\forall\;v'>v$. $\therefore \psi(v') \geq \psi(v)$. But $\psi(v') \neq \psi(v)$ whenever $v' \neq v$, because $U(\theta)$ is obviously unique for any $\theta$. Hence the claim follows.

Now comes the problem.

$U(\psi(v))=v\;\forall\;v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$. $U'$ exists almost everywhere. $\psi$ is strictly increasing therefore $\psi'$ exists almost everywhere as well. Therefore differentiating both sides of the aforementioned equation wrt $v$, $U'(\psi(v))\psi'(v)=1$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$. Hence $U'(\psi(v)) > 0$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$. This is a contradiction because what about the Cantor function.

I'm not able to understand which step is the mistake. I *think* the step where I concluded $U'(\psi(v))\psi'(v)=1$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$ (unless the proof of increasingness of $\psi$ is wrong), but I don't understand why.

Also, are there additional assumptions on $U$ (e.g. absolute continuity) that would make the above conclusion correct?

Comment: You seem to have gone from "$U$ is differentiable almost everywhere" to "$U$ is differentiable at $\psi(v)$ for almost all $v$," without justifying this inference. Is it correct in the case of the Cantor function?

Comment: That's part of my confusion. Why does the former not imply the latter?

Comment: Apply your whole argument to the case where $U$ is the Cantor function. Where is $U$ differentiable? What is $\psi$ in this case? For what values of $v$ is $U$ differentiable at $\psi(v)$? Are those almost all values of $v$?

Comment: Alternatively, try to give a proof for the step I mentioned in my first comment. See where you get stuck.

Comment: Basically Andreas's point is that $\{ v : U \text{ is not differentiable at } \psi(v) \}$ does not have to be null, and actually for something like the Cantor function you would sort of intuitively expect it not to be.

Comment: OK could $\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])$ be a measure 0 set (i.e. a subset of the set of 
 points at which $U$ is NOT differentiable). I guess that's when the former doesn't imply the latter.

Comment: @Ian : Thank you! That's what I eventually figured, as I've tried to describe in my other comment. Could you suggest any additional assumptions on $U$ which would make the above argument go through? (I tried with absolute continuity but I'm not sure how to translate that into $\psi([\underline{v}, \bar{v}])$ having positive measure.

Comment: I would be most grateful if you can suggest any assumptions on $U$ that would make $\psi([\underline{v}, \bar{v}])$ have positive measure so that this problem does not arise.

Comment: I tried to show that absolute continuity is sufficient for that claim of a.e. strictly positive derivative in the set $\psi[\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493568/proof-verification-absolutely-continuous-function-has-a-strictly-positive-deriv 

I would be most grateful if you can tell me if it's correct.