# Proof verification: Absolutely continuous function has a strictly positive derivative a.e. in a given set

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse, absolute-continuity

This is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493106/apparent-contradiction-involving-a-e-differentiability-of-strictly-increasing-f) earlier question of mine.

$U:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is an absolutely continuous function, $U(1)>U(0)$. Let $\max U([0,1])=\overline{v}$. Pick $\underline{v} \in (U(0), \overline{v})$. Define $\psi: [\underline{v},\overline{v}] \rightarrow [0,1]$ as $\psi(v)=\min\limits_{\theta \in [0,1]}\{U(\theta)=v\}$.

We can show that $\psi$ is strictly  increasing. (proven as part of the other question)

Claim: $U'(\psi(v)) > 0$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$.

First we claim: $\int\limits_{\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])} U'(\theta)d\theta=\overline{v}-\underline{v}$

Proof: $\int\limits^{\psi(\overline{v})}_{\psi(\underline{v})} U'(\theta)d\theta=\overline{v}-\underline{v}$. If $\lim\limits_{v' \uparrow v} \psi(v') \neq \lim\limits_{v' \downarrow v} \psi(v')$, $U(\lim\limits_{v' \uparrow v} \psi(v')) = U(\lim\limits_{v' \downarrow v} \psi(v'))=v$. $\therefore\;\int\limits^{\lim\limits_{v' \downarrow v} \psi(v')}_{\lim\limits_{v' \uparrow v} \psi(v')} U'(\theta)d\theta=0$. As $\psi$ is strictly increasing, it has an at most countable no. of discontinuities. Let them be at $\{v_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$. $\therefore\;\overline{v}-\underline{v}=\int\limits^{\psi(\overline{v})}_{\psi(\underline{v})} U'(\theta)d\theta=\int\limits_{\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])} U'(\theta)d\theta + \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\int\limits^{\lim\limits_{v' \downarrow v_n} \psi(v')}_{\lim\limits_{v' \uparrow v_n} \psi(v')} U'(\theta)d\theta=\int\limits_{\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])} U'(\theta)d\theta.$

Hence the set $\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

$U(\psi(v))=v\;\forall\;v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$. $U'$ exists almost everywhere.  $\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])$ has positive Lebesgue measure, so $U'$ exists almost everywhere on $\psi([\underline{v},\overline{v}])$ as well. $\psi$ is strictly increasing therefore $\psi'$ exists almost everywhere in $[\underline{v},\overline{v}]$ as well. Therefore differentiating both sides of the aforementioned equation wrt $v$, $U'(\psi(v))\psi'(v)=1$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$. Hence $U'(\psi(v)) > 0$ for almost all $v \in [\underline{v},\overline{v}]$.

I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct or somewhere I'm implicitly making additional "niceness" assumptions on $U$ unknowingly.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the min over $[0,1]$ means? Because if it is minimizing $U(\theta)$ then it is constant and equal to $v$. Is the $\theta$ you want to minimize??

Comment: $\min _{\theta \in[0,1]}\{U(\theta)=v\}$ is minimum of the set of $\theta$'s for which $U(\theta)=v$. This is the continuous inverse of a closed set, therefore closed, therefore compact, hence minimum exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is much simpler. Assume that there is no subset of  $[0,1]$ of positive measure such that $U'(x)>0$ on that set.

Therefore $U'(x)\,\leq\,0$ on $\,[0,1].$ (at all points at which $U'(x)$ exists).

Then by a standard property of absolutely continuous functions we get:

$\int_{0}^{1}U'(x)=U(1)-U(0)$.

But the integrand is $\,\,U'(x)\,\leq\,0$ and hence the integral is

non-positive i.e. $\,\,U(1)-U(0)\,\leq\,0$ which contradicts our

assumption. So we can infer that the derivative $U'(x)$ HAS to be

positive on some set of positive measure!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! We actually have to show that $U'$ is strictly positive a.e. in $\psi[\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$. $\underline{v}, \overline{v}$ are given. The $\psi$, as it is constructed, is needed for some other purpose, which is not part of this question. Do you think my proof for that makes sense? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the proof once again. But as I mentioned it is not a proof of what I had asked. As I mention in the body of the question, I have to prove that $U'$ is strictly positive a.e. in $\psi[\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$ where $\underline{v}, \overline{v}$ are given and $\psi$ is as given. I don't have to merely prove that there exists some set of positive measure in $[0,1]$ where $U'$ is strictly positive.

Comment: OK! Is $\psi\left [ v_{-},\bar{v} \right ] $ in $[0,1]$??

Comment: Yes.... But I don't think that implies $U'>0$ a.e. on $\psi([\underline{v}, \overline{v}])$, does it? One of the reasons is that $\psi([\underline{v}, \overline{v}])$ need not have measure 1. In fact my central hesitancy is in whether I have shown it correctly that $\psi([\underline{v}, \overline{v}])$ has positive measure. Because without abs cont that's the step that fails, as pointed out here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493106/apparent-contradiction-involving-a-e-differentiability-of-strictly-increasing-f
Please elaborate, in case I have misunderstood you.

Comment: But I do agree - I also think that there's a simpler proof of even that, than what I've written. I'd be most grateful if you can provide any guidance to whether this is correct and/or point me to a simpler proof.